# jquery validation not working in IE7 but does work in IE8

Tags: jquery, validation

I have setup some custom rules for validating a field based on whether an item is selected from a drop down box.

I have 3 values in the drop down

- Please Select
- Did Not Show
- Declined

If the user selects "Did not show" a datepicker appears and they have to enter a valid date
If the user selects "decline" another drop down appears and the user has to select a value from it

The problem is that it work in IE8 but not in IE7. Ideas?

I have set this up as follows;

```
    this.SetupValidations = function() {
            //validations
            LLNP4.validate('#uxReferralAssessmentDetailsForm',
                {
            rules: {
                assessmentDecision: { requiredSelect: "0" },
                NoShowDate: { required: othis.clientDidNotShowValidation },
                DeclinedReason: { requiredSelect: othis.clientDeclinedValidation }
                    }
                });
            }


     this.clientDidNotShowValidation = function() {
            if ($("#uxassessmentDecision option:selected").text().toUpperCase() == "DID NOT SHOW")
            { return true; }
            else
            { return false; }
        }


        this.clientDeclinedValidation = function() {
            if ($("#uxassessmentDecision option:selected").text().toUpperCase() == "DECLINED")
            { return "0"; }
            else
            { return "1"; }
        }


this.ValidateReferralAssessmentSubmission = function() {
        othis.SetupValidations();
        if ($("#uxReferralAssessmentDetailsForm").valid()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }


this.OnAssessmentSave = function () {
        //post back to the server and update the assessment details    
        var options = {
            target: '',
            url: '../Referral/UpdateReferralAssessmentDetails',
            data: { ReferralId: referralIdentifier },
            beforeSubmit: othis.ValidateReferralAssessmentSubmission,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: othis.UpdateReferralAssessmentStatus,
            clearForm: true
        };

        $('#uxReferralAssessmentDetailsForm').ajaxSubmit(options);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you insert a ; at end of every function, like this:

```
this.SetupValidations = function() {
            //validations
            LLNP4.validate('#uxReferralAssessmentDetailsForm',
                {
            rules: {
                assessmentDecision: { requiredSelect: "0" },
                NoShowDate: { required: othis.clientDidNotShowValidation },
                DeclinedReason: { requiredSelect: othis.clientDeclinedValidation }
                    }
                });
            };
```

Comment: thanks. tried that and it probably good standard. Unfortunately didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo?

```
othis.SetupValidations();
```

Isn't "this" instead "othis"?

Comment: thanks. No I make othis an instance on the constrcutor like

function referralEdit() {
    var decision;
    var othis = this;
}